# Typescript Autocomplete example not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and I have to use the angular autocomplete. I copied the code from https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
        .pipe(
           startWith(''),
           map(val => this.filter(val))
        );
}
```

but I get the following error
[ts] The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable'.

Why does it work on the site but not on my machine?

Comment: can't really help as its not explanatory enough and the link wasn't too useful

Comment: what exactly do you need more? The error comes from startWith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem

It seems that I wrote the wrong path to startWith 'rxjs/operator**s**/startWith'

I was using the one without the 's' and that is why I got that error. I would have expected not to find the startWith function instead of providing an error not related to the function